# Programmatically add sites to Java's Exception List

Tags: java

For my job, I am constantly logging into servers (around 3000 unique IP addresses). Every time I try to use the servers built in console, it requires Java, and with Java, I have to add the servers IP address to an exception list for each one. My goal is to make a simple application that adds a given address to the exception site list, then runs it in WebStart.

Is there any text file that houses the site list, or any way to do this?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot so we know what exactly you're having to do?

Answer (score 2):

Further research, found the location I needed. This file houses all the sites on your exception list.

```
%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites
```

Sorry to waste the readers time!